# Как отображать перетаскиваемый объект при Drag&Drop?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

Имеется форма с двумя панелями, в нижней панели расположены типы машин, к примеру. С помощью Drag&Drop с нижней панели перетаскивается шаблон машины в верхнюю панель. Как при перетаскивании сделать так, чтобы за курсором следовал полупрозрачный перетаскиваемый элемент управления? Например, как при перетаскивании иконок на рабочем столе

Comment: Эта штука называется Adorner

Answer (score 0):

Я люблю использовать нугет пакет `gong-wpf-dragdrop`. С ним перетаскивание легко и непринужденно делается.

Просто задал в ресурсах формы такой шаблон

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DragAdorner">
        <Image Height="100" Source="{Binding}" Opacity="0.5"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Потом задал два `ListBox`, они аналогичны, разве что биндинг на две разных коллекции сделал, потому привожу только один:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" 
        dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
        dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate="{StaticResource DragAdorner}" 
        dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Height="95" Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

И всё - перекидывание работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]